# Compute the determinant of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

$$A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & b & c \\ b & c & 1 \\ c & 1 & b \end{matrix}\right]$$ $R_2-bR_1$ & $R_3-cR_1$

$$ = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & b & c \\ 0 & c-b^2 & 1-bc \\ 0 & 1-cb & b-c^2 \end{matrix}\right]$$ $R_3(c-b^2)$

$$ = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & b & c \\ 0 & c-b^2 & 1-bc \\ 0 & (1-cb)(c-b^2) & (b-c^2)(c-b^2) \end{matrix}\right]$$ $R_3-(1-cb)R_2$

$$ = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & b & c \\ 0 & c-b^2 & 1-bc \\ 0 & 0 & D \end{matrix}\right]$$

$D=(b-c^2)(c-b^2)-(1-bc)(1-bc)(1-cb)$
$=bc-b^3-c^3+b^2c^2-(1-cb-bc+b^2c^2)$
$=bc-b^3-c^3+b^2c^2-1+cb+bc-b^2c^2$
$=-b^3-c^3+3cb-1$

So then I'd have to multiply the main diagonal which gives me the equation: 
$Det(A)=1(c-b^2)(-b^3-c^3+3bc-1)$

In class my professor did an example similar to this where he used the lower triangular method.

I know with a different method that the answer should be $-b^3-c^3+3bc-1$, so I'm really confused. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or needs further explanation please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is $-b^3-c^3+3bc-1$. If you would like someone to tell you where you made a mistake, you would need to post how you got to your result.

Comment: Could you show your work? It would be easier to find the error in it.

Comment: If you multiply a row by a constant, you change the value of the determinant.

Comment: When you multiply $R_3$ by $(c-b^2)$ you inflate the determinant by a factor of $(c-b^2)$ and so you need to factor that out again before you are done.

Comment: The anser is $-b^3-c^3+3 b c -1$. You can easily get this results by using the sarrus rule.

Comment: @DougM Oh! In which step would I factor it out?

Comment: The singular is actually *matrix*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this step
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & b & c \\ 0 & c-b^2 & 1-bc \\ 0 & 1-cb & b-c^2 \end{matrix}\right]$$ 
you should multiply row 2 by $-\frac{1-bc}{c-b^2}$ and add it to row 3 to get
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & b & c \\ 0 & c-b^2 & 1-bc \\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{(1-bc)^2}{c-b^2}+b-c^2 \end{matrix}\right].$$

Multiplying the diagonal entries you get $-b^3-c^3+3bc-1$. Alternatively, when you multiplied a row by $(c-b^2)$ you could note that this multiplies the determinant by $c-b^2$. Thus the determinant of the original matrix is what you found divided by $c-b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix $M$ :

$$M= \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{bmatrix}$$

is given by :

$$\det(M) = a_{11} \Bigg|\begin{matrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix}\Bigg| - a_{12}\Bigg| \begin{matrix} a_{21} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{33}\end{matrix} \Bigg| + a_{13} \Bigg| \begin{matrix} a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32}\end{matrix} \Bigg|$$

Applying this to your given matrix $A$, should yield you the result :

$$\det(A) = -b^3 + 3bc - c^3 - 1$$

If you need help to find where you're wrong with your solution, please make sure you edit your question and contain it in it.

[Here's a cool widget to help you check your $3\times 3$ determinant results !](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=7fcb0a2c0f0f41d9f4454ac2d8ed7ad6)

Comment: I know but I'm worried he wants us to do it with lower triangular method and I also want to understand that method just in case. I've added what I've done.